# Wrong row gets deleted in DataGridView bound to DataAdapter

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, delete-row, dataadapter

**Situation**:

I'm writing a Winforms app using C# in VS2013 with .NET4.0.

I have a datagridview which I bind to a DataAdapter linked to a MySQL table.   I'm performing updates using the DataAdapter's Update method.   Due to the unconventional handling of dates and booleans in the MySQL table I set my own SQL commands rather than using CommandBuilder.   These are fed by parameters set before calling Update.  I call Update on RowValidated.

For inserting and amending this works fine.

**Issue**:

In the datagridview, when the user selects a single row, I want them to be able to hit delete and have the row removed from both the grid and the database.   When I try this the row disappears from the datagridview and of course the cursor moves to a different row.  But the *database* row that gets deleted is the new datagridview row that the cursor has fallen on.  This is almost certainly because I use datagridview.CurrentRow to set the parameter for the delete command and I assume that at this stage the current row has indeed changed.

**Question**:

How do I amend this arrangement so the delete will work correctly?  Clearly the underlying issue is that the row has disappeared from the grid before the database update takes place but I'm not sure how to resolve that.  I suspect the solution may lie in handling things through different events but I'm not sure which.

Comment: Don't remove data from the datgridview directly.  Delete the data from the datatable and the datagridview should automatically get updated.  The row number of the DataGridview and dataTable should always be the same.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng.  So now in UserDeletingRow I manually delete the required row, refill the adapter and then refresh the datagridview.  This _appears_ fine and the required row disappears from the grid.  However in the database the required row has gone _and_ the new row on which the cursor has fallen.  The later is probably because RowValidated has still been triggered causing the adapter's Update. So how do I either a) prompt the Update method to handle the delete of the required row or b) delete that required row manually and prevent Update from carrying out the subsequent delete.

Comment: You have bypassed the command builder.  The command builder takes a Select command and creates three additional commands : Update, Insert, and Delete.  I think you need all 4 commands for the update to work properly.  An update need to be able to Delete rows.

Comment: I already defined all four adapter commands Select, Update, Insert and Delete.  The problem is that Delete is removing the wrong row.  I can manually delete the correct row but the adapter.Update still then goes on to remove the "new" current row.

Comment: Maybe the datagridview is just not getting updated properly and the datatable is correct.  Try setting the datasource = null, then back to the table datasource = dt.  This will force the datagridview to update.

Comment: So in UserDeletingRow I've tried to call adapter.Update first before refreshing the dgv.  The correct Delete command is built but nothing updates however because nothing has changed at this point.  The only way I can think of to make the adapter.Update do the delete is to delete the dgv row first but then I lose the context of the row as it's gone.  If I try deleting the row manually that works but then adapter.Update fires (from RowValidated) and deletes another row.

Comment: Instead of deleting the row from the dgv delete the same row from the datatable.  Then call the update.  The index of the dgv is the same as the datatable.  the RowValidated may delete another row but after to refresh the datagridview by setting datasource to null and back to the daattable the dgv should show accurate results.  You may need to override the RowValidated to prevent it from deleting rows automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok generating the SQL Delete command doesn't work when I reference CurrentRow from the dgv because by the time I'm building my parameters and doing the adapter.Update that dgv row has gone.  That's why I end up deleting the wrong row.  So I've solved it like this:

- In the UserDeletingRow event I'm storing the primary key value for the row being deleted.
- In RowValidated, where I call the adapter.Update I first use the stored primary key to build the correct SQL Delete command.  Even though the row has already gone from the dgv the database delete now works correctly.

Relieved to get this working but this does seem like a pretty inelegant solution.  Grateful if anyone knows of a slicker way of handling this.  I'd be intrigued to know just what logic the CommandBuilder would have used.  (Sadly I can't use CommandBuilder because my Inserts and Updates need to do Unix_TIMESTAMP conversions).